# How do I create multiple Facebook bots with a single platform?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I have a Facebook bot and I have connected it with a Facebook page. However to have it publicly available I have to wait the approval from Facebook.

Not a problem if you have to make one single bot, huge problem if you have to do it on scale level (eg: 100+ bots).

Platform as [Chatfuel](https://chatfuel.com/) or [Content Api](http://content.api.ai/facebook-messenger-bot) allow you to just select the page you own and connect the bot automatically.

In minutes the bot is ***publicly available***, skipping the review phase (apparently) in Facebook.

I didn’t find any info about that on the [Facebook developer guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review), there is a sort of internal API not available for everyone? If so how can you request access to that?

Comment: why would anyone make 100+ bots in a row? i assume those platforms use the same bot, not 100+ different ones.

Comment: The purpose is to create chatbot "as a services" for different users. Did you check out chatfuel?

Comment: So what? Main purpose of review is to protect users from malicious apps - so it doesn’t matter if you create one, or a hundred - they need to be reviewed. There is no “skipping” that. Those services you mention most likely do not create a new app id for each customer, but use one to serve several.

Comment: @CBroe The point is not to just skip the review phase :) I am trying to understand if those platform are somehow connected with facebook and have an agreement that allow them to skip the review phase because they are in charge of checking that the bots are compliant with the rules. I am working on a similar platform and I'm trying to understand how to publish more bots without using the same app id for each customer :) Do you know for sure that those platforms work with the same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook Messenger bots are published for a page (which is the bot *identity*) using one or more applications (which defines the *webhook* where messages are sent). 
So the *application* must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. After that, any page can be 'attached' to this application, using the standard Facebook authorization flow in order to get an access token for this page by the approved application.

So Chatfuel and others alreay have their application approved, and now any page can be connected to it.

Comment: Thanks :) That's what all people are saying about that. The problem I find is that it is against Facebook guide line and I don't know if it will be a solution valid in the next year. You know something about that?

Comment: Where in guidelines did you find something about this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review here it looks like it is only for one app.. I am getting it wrong? :)

Comment: @SimoneImbrescia : were you able to figure out  way? i have the same issue, my app is approved from facebook but i am not able to use that app to post on other pages i donot own.

Comment: @tnt_the_guy the only solution that I figure out is the one proposed. I've never implemented it however :)